# Should I use 'is' or 'are' in ambiguous sentences like this one?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammatical-number, verb-agreement

I understand that you should use 'is' for singular and 'are' for plural, but in this sentence I am not sure which applies.

Take the sentence

> Bees are an important part of our ecosystem.

Let's say I wanted to reword it so that the subject is at the end of the sentence. Which of these two is correct?

> An important part of our ecosystem are bees.

> An important part of our ecosystem is bees.

To me they both sound wrong, so I want to know how I can determine correct grammar in these cases.

Comment: To be honest I wouldn't rephrase it. The original is fine but I would find it difficult to rephrase it in the way you are suggesting. Both of your attempts sound clumsy to me. What is your reason for wanting to rephrase?

Comment: @BoldBen This is just an example but one might want to write something like "an important part of our ecosystem is bees, which...". Obviously I could rewrite this as well and avoid the problem but I'm really asking about the underlying grammar in cases like this, not this particular sentence.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks for the link. That discussion is quite technical but if I understand it correctly, then it should be "...is bees"?

Comment: Yes. Although it is sometimes arguable, the noun phrase (some would say determiner phrase) at the start of a sentence with the verb 'be' is almost always considered to be the subject. And verb agreement is always with the subject, never the complement (as here) or object (where applicable). // These mis-matched pairings often sound rather awkward even when they're grammatical. Surprisingly, I find 'Bees form an important part of our ecosystem' not to present even the slight jar I feel with 'Bees are an important part of our ecosystem'.

Comment: I don't find that strange at all @EdwinAshworth. The word 'form conveys the idea that each individual bee is a subcomponent of an important part of the ecosystem which the word 'are' does not convey.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I am not really good in English, but I have an opinion that may be correct. As I know, the form of "be" defines from an attached noun. Here your noun is plural (bees), so I have no reasons to write "is" there.